# Creating method on how to have Selecting MAX Function in C# with SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have this kind of method on inserting data

```
private void InsertReceipt()
    {   
        decimal Stub;
        Stub = Math.Floor(decimal.Parse(txtAmount.Text) / 2000);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Ticket(CustomerID, Date, Store, Amount, NoStub)" +
                    "VALUES (@CustomerID, @Date, @Store, @Amount, @NoStub) ";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", txtCustomerID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dtpDate.Value.Date.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Store", txtStore.Text);
        decimal amount = decimal.Parse(txtAmount.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", amount);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@NoStub", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Stub;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();            
    }
```

I just want to have a method that if you insert a data in table "Ticket" there's another table will be updating.

```
    CustomerID      Date        Store      Amount      NoStub
         1        6/7/2013      Nike       4000          2
         2        6/7/2013      Adidas     6000          3
```

This table will be updating, for example I will be using table named "StubRange", This output will be generate.

```
 RangeID         CustomerID      NoStub       TickerStart      TickerEnd
   1                1              2           00001           00002
   2                2              3           00003           00005
```

I just want to learned how to have this kind of kind of method.

Comment: Insert Triggers are your friend.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is an `After Insert` [trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx).
Basically you can think of it as an event that triggers after an insert takes place (hence trigger...).

Your trigger should look something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER YourTriggerName --The name of your trigger
ON Ticket --The table it will be observing
 AFTER INSERT,UPDATE --It will trigger after insert / update
AS
--The actions you want to do. For example:
DECLARE @CustomerId int

SET @CustomerId = (SELECT CustomerId FROM inserted) --you might want to use 'inserted' table

--Inset values
Insert into StubRange (CustomerID , NoStub) 
Select Distinct ins.CustomerID, ins.NoStub 
From Inserted ins

--Update existing records
UPDATE StubRange
set --Set what ever it is you want to update
WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId
```

More about Inserted table - According to [Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx):

> The inserted table stores copies of the affected rows during INSERT
>   and UPDATE statements. During an insert or update transaction, new
>   rows are added to both the inserted table and the trigger table. The
>   rows in the inserted table are copies of the new rows in the trigger
>   table.

Comment: Sir I just want to have a kind of method using codes in C#.net

Comment: I must advise against. If you want to keep your data integrity - I would go for triggers. If you Insist on a C# method, what is stopping you from writing a similar method as the one you have posted for updating 'StubRange' And calling it every time you call 'InsertReceipt' (again, Triggers will be better as they run, by definition, after the insert and they are part of the insert transaction.)

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to write a insert trigger when ever you insert record in Ticket table. You can refer below syntax to create trigger. This is a Oracle syntax

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_INSERT_STUBRANGE 
AFTER INSERT ON TICKET
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    raise_exception                Exception;
BEGIN

        --WRITE YOUR INSERT STATEMENT HERE

Exception
         when raise_exception then
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, sqlerrm );
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will create an insert trigger on your table1 on updating table1 , table2 will b updated with CustomerID, NoStub  from table 1 and rest of properties depends on your business logic

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_Update_table
ON [tableName1]
FOR INSERT
AS
Begin
    Insert into tableName2 (CustomerID , NoStub) 
    Select Distinct i.CustomerID, i.NoStub 
    from Inserted i
End
```